# Is it okay to put an adverbial of time between a subject and a verb?

Tags: word-order

Is it okay to put an adverbial of time between a subject and a verb? For example, 'the parliament on March 19 passed a bill that [...]'. I know I can put it at the beginning ('on March 19, [...]'), but it's not always applicable. For example, it may be too clumsy if there's another "isolated part of the sentence" (sorry, I don't know how to say it in English or even in my mother tongue) in front: 'On March 19, in order to fix this problem, the parliament passed [...]'

Comment: Yes, it's okay. But the natural place for the the date would be at the start of this sentence unless you had a special reason to place it between the subject and the verb.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you should set it off with commas,

> Parliament, on March 19, passed a bill ....

Do you need it there?  Is there any reason not to move it to the beginning or the end

> On March 19, Parliament passed a bill...

> Parliament passed a pill on march 19th ...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what it is that you are talking about, ie what is the subject. If you are talking about the parliament, then it goes as the subject of your sentence with commas seperating the time clause: The parliament, on March 19th, passed...
If the date was your subject, you would say:
On March 19th the parliament passed...

This is to maintain the focus on your subject. If the subject keeps changing, then the reader may find it difficult to grasp the point you are making.

Comment: The subject is ***the parliament***, no matter where you put ***on March 19th*.**